# Динамическое обновление интерфейса

Tags: python, ооп, многопоточность, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты

Есть программа, в которой необходимо сделать динамическое обновление интерфейса в ходе процесса работы приложения.

Есть ли у *PyQt5* подобные инструменты?

Есть программа по обработке некоторых файлов. В ходе её процесса нужно выводить на экран статус выполнения и прочую доп. информацию.

Дело в том, что метод, который использую я, как мне кажется, не самый оптимальный и поэтому во время процесса программа замораживается (обновление не идёт).

Вот упрощённая версия программы. Да, тут ничего не виснет, но сам принцип сохранён.

```
from sys import argv, exit
import time
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from threading import Thread


# options
W_SIZE = (480, 360)
W_TITLE = "Template program"
W_ICON = ""
W_FIXEDSIZE = False


# класс данных
class MyProcessData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 0


# класс для обработки
class MyProcessClass:
    def process(self, update_function):
        data = MyProcessData()

        for i in range(1000):
            data.num += 5
            update_function(data)
            time.sleep(0.0001)


# интерфейс
class GUI():
    def __init__(self, window) -> None:
        self.Title_Label = QtWidgets.QLabel(window)
        self.Title_Label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 50, 20))


# Окно программы
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, wsize: tuple):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(250, 250, *wsize)

    def setup(self, title, icon="", fixedsize=False):
        self.setWindowTitle(title)
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(icon))
        self.setFixedSize(self.geometry) if fixedsize else None


# класс всей программы
class Application:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.qapp = QtWidgets.QApplication(argv)
        self.window = MainWindow(W_SIZE)
        self.ui = GUI(self.window)

    def updateUI(self, data: MyProcessData):
        self.ui.Title_Label.setText(str(data.num))

    def start(self):
        self.window.setup(W_TITLE, W_ICON, W_FIXEDSIZE)
        self.connectUI()
        process = MyProcessClass()
        t = Thread(target=process.process, args=(self.updateUI,))
        t.start()
        

        self.window.show()
        exit(self.qapp.exec_())


    def connectUI(self):
        pass


app = Application()
app.start()
```

*Объясняю принцип работы*

*Есть общий класс `Application` - это вся программа целиком, тут хранится всё. 
`MainWindow` и `GUI` это всё окно программы, классы отвечают за интерфейс. 
`MyProcessClass` и `MyProcessData` это классы обработчика, там проходят все вычисления.

По итогу создаётся объект класса `MyProcessClass` и вызывается функция `process` в новом потоке, в нее передается аргумент: функция, которая отвечает за обновление данных. Каждый новый цикл выполнения "обработки" информация на экране обновляется*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, у *PyQt5* подобные инструменты есть.

Например:

- Класс [**QThread**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html) предоставляет независимый от платформы способ управления потоками.
- [**Сигналы и слоты**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) используются для связи между объектами. Механизм сигналов и слотов является центральной особенностью Qt и, вероятно, той частью, которая больше всего отличается от функций, предоставляемых другими фреймворками.

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


# класс данных
class MyProcessData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 0
        
        
# класс для обработки
class MyProcessClass(QThread):
    stepChanged = pyqtSignal(int)
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        myProcessData = MyProcessData() 
        self.data = myProcessData.num    

    def run(self):
        for i in range(1000):
            self.data += 5
            self.stepChanged.emit(self.data)
            self.msleep(50)                       # установите нужный вам интервал в мс.
            

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)  

        self.title_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.title_label.setObjectName("title_label")
        self.title_label.setStyleSheet('color: #B20600; font-size: 77px;')
        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start") 
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btn_clicked)

        layout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)        
        layout.addWidget(self.title_label, 0, 0, 2, 2, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 2, 1, alignment=Qt.AlignRight)
  
        self.thread = None
        
    def btn_clicked(self):
        if self.thread is None:
            self.thread = MyProcessClass()
            self.thread.stepChanged.connect(self.onStepChanged)
            self.thread.finished.connect(self.onFinished)
            self.thread.start()
            self.pushButton.setText("Stop")
        else:
            self.thread.terminate()
            self.thread = None
            self.pushButton.setText("Start")
            
    def onStepChanged(self, data):
        self.title_label.setNum(data)

    def onFinished(self):   
        self.thread = None
        self.pushButton.setText("Start")   


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(480, 360)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]